# Downloading string from URL and loading ListBox with the returned data?

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm downloading a string file from a website, I need to get all the information and load the listBox with the text, unfortunately Im getting an error every time I click in the button event.

My code:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var text = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(@"http://photo-51.netau.net/changelog");
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@text, System.Text.Encoding.Default);//here I have an Invalid Path Character error
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(line);
            }
```

I have and Invalid Character in the Path. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Michael I can't find a answear for my question in this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamReader` you're using expects path to the file to read. So `@text` you're passing to it is actually treated as path to the file, that's why you get an exception.

You can reference MSDN, for [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor. As you can see, string parameter is defined as

> The complete file path to be read.

Now there are multiple ways of reading string line by line, I'll put here one that requires least changes in your original code

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var text = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(@"http://photo-51.netau.net/changelog");
StringReader sr = new StringReader(text);

string line;
while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  listBox1.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still showing the same error message, but anyways, thanks for helping

Comment: Just tried this code on my machine, works perfectly fine for me. Can you please put more details - are you using exactly same code as I posted?